# Will a 100% AMP site (no desktop version) appear in desktop Google SERPs?

Tags: amp-html

I have read a few articles and comments which say things like "Google will only serve AMP pages to mobile devices" and "my AMP site doesn't appear in desktop search".

So my question is... if a site is build 100% in AMP, with no non-AMP version, will that site still appear in desktop Google search results?

Answer (score 3):

The AMP project homepage is built entirely out of AMP. So, yes it will appear in desktop search results, the difference being is that it won't be served via Google's caches and it won't have the AMP logo to differentiate it from other results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it appear in Google Desktop SERPs and I've an example. Go to Google from your Laptop, PC or any other desktop computer and google "how to change Author box gravatar size" you'll find a result from https://wp-me.com appearing in the results!
I don't know why this happened? maybe because the Non-AMP page isn't indexed!